# Remembering last window position by window manager or force it via xorg option parameters

Tags: linux, xorg, kde-4

Guys how come that window position of apps on screen is "remembered" only for some of them ? When you close it at  x y wigth height and then start again.

chrome, pidgin, xchat  works,  but  Dolphin, firefox etc. does not
It seems to be an issue for firefox  https://bugs.launchpad.net/firefox/+bug/204480

but dolphin ?
It is extremely annoying, especially on dual screen. One way is using xorg's  option x y width height, but I don't even know how to start firefox with these.

I'm using nouveau driver and have dual monitor setup. I'd like to have my IDE started on left monitor and rest of the apps on the right one. But it seems to be impossible task.

How would you do that?

I'm on kde 4.5.5, xorg-server-1.9.5, firefox 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On KDE you can right-click on title bar of the application, then "Advanced" and you will see:
**"Special Window Settings"** and **"Special Application Settings"**.
From there you can set the window matching criteria and the action you want to be taken.
For example in the **"Size & Position"** tab there is **"Size"** and **"Position"** (as can be expected), as well as other settings which can be applied initially (when the application starts), forced or remembered (remember the settings on close and apply them on start)

Answer (score 0):

This surely is an application problem. When it's shutdown, the application should save its size and position and use those arguments to position itself when next launched.

Comment: I do not think it is an application problem, it is more likely to be a Window Manager problem.